# How to extend scopes for an access token driven session

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

Let's assume we have a system that uses an oauth process with access and refresh tokens to authenticate a user's client software. The lifetime of these tokens basically represent a user session - the client software will refresh the access token until the user explicitly logs out.
Now new features are added on the backend that require new scopes. How can the access token used by the client be extended to have these additional tokens?

The oauth spec seems not to allow extending access tokens gaining more scopes when they are refreshed, so it seems following the official flows would require the user to log in again to add additional scopes, but ideally we would avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user authenticates, and optionally consents, the authorization server should record and audit this event, along with the claims and scopes issued. Think of this as the OAuth delegation. It ensures that token refresh cannot elevate permissions.

When there are new software releases, and these permissions change, it is a best practice to involve the user again and record a new delegation, since the client is operating with new permissions.

After a software upgrade, older access tokens may still be in use. These will not have access to newer features though. To gain access, the user must logout, then login again.

This is how many security systems work. Eg Windows logins based on Kerberos have the same end user requirements, if a user's domain group memberships change.

One option is for clients to ask an API whether the current scopes are up to date when the app is started. If not up to date, the client can inform the user that a new login is required.